# Панель, блокирующая поворот экарана для UITableView

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, ios

Нужна панель, которая иногда (по определенному действию пользователя) появляется снизу UITableView и блокирует дисплей и реакцию на поворот экрана (вертикально-горизонтально). Как лучше сделать? Создать nib для этой панели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да не обязательно создавать целый ниб для этой панели, можно просто создать еще одно вью программно, которое будет нести на себе эту панель, вью наложится поверх UITableView  и не даст возможности что либо делать пользователю.